# How to configure path in NextJS

Tags: next.js, url-rewriting

I have the following addresses `/blog/post-1`, `/blog/post-2` and I want to rewrite all paths to `/post-1`, `/post-2`. I configure in the file next.config.js as follows

```js
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/:slug',
      destination: '/blog/:slug',
    },
  ]
}
```

However, the old path and the new path both work? What should I do?

Comment: _"the old path and the new path both work"_ - Isn't that the desired behaviour? Which path do you not want to work?

Comment: @juliomalves I just want `/posts-1` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have them set up the wrong way around if you are trying to redirect from `/blog/post-1` to `/post-1/` and you need the path parameter.

From the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/blog/:path*',
        destination: '/:path*', // The :path parameter is used here so will not be automatically passed in the query
      },
    ]
  },
}
```